# Conditional Html inline style attribute using razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Using Razor, in the following iteration of items in a `View`, how can we make the `CustName` input `readonly` if `CustName` is not empty

```
@model  ABCTest.Models.ViewModels.MyViewModel
...
<table>
@for (int i=0; i<Model.CuttomersOrders.Count(); i++)
{
 <td>...</td>
...
 <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(c => c.CuttomersOrders[i].CustName)
 </td>
...
}
...
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditionally call the helper method with the relevant htmlAttributes overload value.

`EditorFor` helper method does not have an overload which takes the htmlAttributes dictionary. So you can use the `TextBoxFor` helper method instead.

```
@for(int i=0; i<Model.CuttomersOrders.Count(); i++)
{
  <tr>
    <td>
    @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.CuttomersOrders[i].CustName))
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CuttomersOrders[i].CustName,new { @readonly=true})
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CuttomersOrders[i].CustName)
    }
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

Remember, the existence of the `readonly` attribute will make the input element readonly irrespective of the value. So basically the below 2 lines will render a readonly input element.

```
<input  readonly="False" type="text" value="Java" />
<input i readonly="true" type="text" value="Java" />
```

Comment: It seems we can't do it with style attribute of `<td>`, correct?

Comment: your question says you want to make the input element readonly.  readonly is not a valid attribute for td.

Comment: Thanks. Two points were worth noticing for me 1. Use of readonly regardless of true or false 2. Use of `Model.CuttomersOrders[i].CustName` in `if` statement. I was trying lambda expression inside `String.IsNullOrEmpty(....)` but `VS2017` was not accepting it.